# How to change the default file manager for OSX?

Tags: macos, finder, quicksilver

I've downloaded muCommander and find it better than Finder. When I open folders with QuickSilver it still uses Finder, though. How do I change this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change Finder. But you can download a third party file manager and add it to login items: System Preferences - users & groups - login items

Answer (score 0):

[According to Apple Tech Note TN2062](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2062/_index.html), you can replace the Finder by telling `launchd` to run something else upon login:

> You can change the global `Finder` by changing the `Program` property of that plist. However, it is generally preferable to override the system-wide `Finder` by placing a modified plist in `/Library/LaunchAgents`.

Be sure to read the entire thing for warnings. It sounds like a risky idea.

If that doesn't work, QuickSilver might be hard-wired to launch Finder. In that case, you will have to contact its developers and ask them for a new setting.

(Note that things like the File > Open dialog will still use Finder, since that is part of the operating system.)

Comment: That only disables opening Finder at login and reopening it automatically. It doesn't change the default application for opening folders.